# Spark streaming program stuck in a reduce transformation

Tags: java, spark-streaming

I am struggling to find a solution for this problem.

So basically, I want to make a first processing on an RDD and Inside that processing make call to a function that does a second processing before returning its value to th first processing to continue its process.

The problem is when trying to get the value from the second process via reduce or foreach methods, the program gets stuck.
The program works normaly if I do not use one of these transformations.

Here is the log :

```
2016-06-18 08:04:51,310 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.util.Utils - Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 44493.
2016-06-18 08:04:51,622 [sparkDriverActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
2016-06-18 08:04:51,668 [sparkDriverActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  Remoting - Starting remoting
2016-06-18 08:04:51,831 [sparkDriverActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  Remoting - Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@142.100.1.5:45617]
2016-06-18 08:04:51,841 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.util.Utils - Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 45617.
2016-06-18 08:04:51,861 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.SparkEnv - Registering MapOutputTracker
2016-06-18 08:04:51,886 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.SparkEnv - Registering BlockManagerMaster
2016-06-18 08:04:51,999 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.SparkEnv - Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
2016-06-18 08:04:52,230 [main] INFO  org.spark-project.jetty.server.Server - jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
2016-06-18 08:04:52,280 [main] INFO  org.spark-project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
2016-06-18 08:04:52,280 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.util.Utils - Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
2016-06-18 08:04:52,282 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI - Started SparkUI at http://142.100.1.5:4040
2016-06-18 08:04:52,384 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.util.Utils - Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 37259.
2016-06-18 08:04:52,385 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService - Server created on 37259
2016-06-18 08:04:53,201 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Created broadcast 0 from textFile at HelloSparkWorld.java:31
2016-06-18 08:04:53,323 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Starting job: foreach at HelloSparkWorld.java:43
2016-06-18 08:04:53,422 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] INFO  org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
2016-06-18 08:04:53,908 [Executor task launch worker-0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2016-06-18 08:04:53,945 [Executor task launch worker-0] INFO  org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Starting job: reduce at HelloSparkWorld.java:73
2016-06-18 08:04:53,962 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] INFO  org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Created broadcast 2 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
2016-06-18 08:04:53,971 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] INFO  org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Created broadcast 3 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
```

And the code :

```
public class HelloSparkWorld {

    private static JavaSparkContext sc;
    private static JavaPairRDD<String, Float> doc;
    public static void main(String... argv) {

        //Create a spark config with a single local instance
        SparkConf config = new SparkConf().setAppName("HelloSparkWorld").setMaster("local[1]");

        //Create a context
        sc = new JavaSparkContext(config);

        //Load join doc
        doc = sc
                .textFile("src/main/resources/file.txt")
                .mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s.split("\\t+")[0], Float.parseFloat(s.split("\\t+")[1])));

        //First computation making call to getNumber to process "line" via second computation
        String line = "hello world";
        ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add(line);
            sc
                .parallelize(l)
                .flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s+")))
                .mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, getNumber(line)))
                    .foreach(s -> System.out.println(s._1()));
    }

    public static float getNumber(String text) {
        ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add(text);


        //Second Computation
        Tuple2<String, Tuple2<Integer, Float>> tuple = sc
                .parallelize(l)
                .flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s+")))
                .mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1))
                .join(doc)
                .reduce( (a, b) -> new Tuple2<>(a._1(), new Tuple2<>(a._2()._1()+b._2()._1(), a._2()._2()+b._2()._2())));

        float avg = tuple._2()._2()/tuple._2()._1();
        System.out.println(avg);
        return avg;
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot have rdd inside another rdd .

Comment: thank you for your help!